# What is the difference between cantatrice and chanteuse?

Tags: sens, vocabulaire

I read [this page](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantatrice) and wondered in what sense *cantatrice* differs from *chanteuse*, two terms for a singing woman. Is *cantatrice* more official, for professional/succesful singers, as opposed to *chanteuse*?

Answer (score 4):

Not every *chanteuse* (female singer) can be a *cantatrice*.

The latter is restricted to famous classical music singers so for example Madonna, Beyoncé or Céline Dion, whatever their career and success do not qualify for this designation.